# How do I reset a game level

Tags: xna-4.0, farseer-physics-engine

I have managed to implement a screen state system which I use to access the game. When the the character has collided with an enemy tile the game ends by going to a seperate game over screen. After being re-directed to the start screen the player can choose to start a new game. However the old level is still loaded and the old player character is still in contact with the enemy tile and the game over screen is loaded instantly.

How can I reload the level as new rather than load the previous game?

I have included the main game class below, Thanks

```
using FarseerPhysics.Dynamics;
using FarseerPhysics.Factories;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using FarseerPhysics.DebugViews;
using FarseerPhysics.HelloWorld.Physics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using FarseerPhysics.HelloWorld.GameObjects;
using TiledLib;
using System;

namespace FarseerPhysics.HelloWorld
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main class for our game, most of the work ealier on in the project will
    /// be done in this class but we should move some of the work into level classes.
    /// </summary>
    public class Sum :Game
    {
        //Graphics
        private GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        //Sprite Batch- used to draw texture2D to the screen
        private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        //Holds the previous input state
        private KeyboardState oldKeyState;
        private GamePadState oldPadState;
        //For drawing text to the screen, mainly debug info
        private SpriteFont gameFont;
        public float playerSpeed;
        public float jumpHeight;
        public int jumpTimes;
        public float gravity;
        private int count = 0;
        private int count2 = 0;
        public float friction;
        public float bounce;
        public float velocity;

        //World, this is the physics simulation, we will use this to add
        //remove objects from the physics
        private World world;

        // Simple camera controls
        private Matrix view;
        private Vector2 cameraPosition;
        private Vector2 screenCenter;


        //Physics debug overlay, shows what has been added to the simulation
        private DebugViewXNA debugPhysicsView;
        private Matrix debugProjection;
        private Matrix debugView;

        //Holds every game sprite on the screen, this has been loaded by us and
        //not from the map
        List<GameSprite> displayList;

        //The Sprite we are controlling, is there a better way to control something
        GameSprite playerSprite;
        MenuComponent menuComponent;

        KeyboardState keyboardState;
        KeyboardState oldKeyboardState;

        GameScreen activeScreen;
        StartScreen startScreen;
        ActionScreen actionScreen;
        OptionsScreen optionsScreen;
        PopUpScreen quitScreen;

        public bool game = false;
        public bool gameEnds = false;
        public bool playerDead = false;

        //The Tiled Map we are using at the moment
        Map gameMap;

        GameSprite movingPlatform;

        //If we are not on the XBOX360 platform
#if !XBOX360
        //Some instruction text to show
        const string Text = "Press A or D to rotate the ball\n" +
                            "Press Space to jump\n" +
                            "Press Shift + W/S/A/D to move the camera"+
                            "Press F1 to enable/disable physics debug";
#else
                const string Text = "Use left stick to move\n" +
                                    "Use right stick to move camera\n" +
                                    "Press A to jump\n"+
                                    "Press Back to enable/disable physics debug";
#endif    
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public void VariableChanger()
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Content/TextEditor.txt");

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] chart = line.Split('=');
                if (chart[0].ToLower() == "playerspeed")
                {
                    playerSpeed = float.Parse(chart[1]);
                }
                if (chart[0] == "jumpHeight")
                {
                    jumpHeight = float.Parse(chart[1]);
                }
                if (chart[0] == "jumpTimes")
                {
                    jumpTimes = int.Parse(chart[1]);
                }
                if (chart[0] == "gravity")
                {
                    gravity = float.Parse(chart[1]);
                }
                if (chart[0] == "friction")
                {
                    friction = float.Parse(chart[1]);
                }
                if (chart[0] == "bounce")
                {
                    bounce = float.Parse(chart[1]);
                }
                if (chart[0] == "velocity")
                {
                    velocity = float.Parse(chart[1]);
                }
            }
        }




        public Sum()
        {
            VariableChanger();
            //Initialise the graphics system
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            //Width and Height of the screen
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1200;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 880;

            //The root directory for all assets
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            //This holds sprites that are loaded by us and not from the tiled Map
            displayList = new List<GameSprite>();
            //Create Physics Simulation with Gavity of 9.8. We should load this
            //value from a text file
            world = new World(new Vector2(0, gravity));
        } 

        public void LoadGame()
        {
            VariableChanger();
            // Initialize camera controls
            view = Matrix.Identity;
            cameraPosition = Vector2.Zero;

            //Calculate screen centre
            screenCenter = new Vector2(graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2f, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2f);

            //Create Sprite batch for drawing our sprites later
            //batch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            //load font from drawing text
            gameFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("font");

            //Create our debug physics view
            debugPhysicsView = new DebugViewXNA(world);
            debugPhysicsView.Enabled = true;
            debugPhysicsView.LoadContent(GraphicsDevice, Content);
            debugPhysicsView.DebugPanelPosition = new Vector2(600.0f, 0.0f);
            debugPhysicsView.AppendFlags(DebugViewFlags.Shape);
            debugPhysicsView.AppendFlags(DebugViewFlags.Joint);
            debugPhysicsView.AppendFlags(DebugViewFlags.DebugPanel);
            debugPhysicsView.AppendFlags(DebugViewFlags.ContactPoints);
            debugPhysicsView.AppendFlags(DebugViewFlags.AABB);
            debugPhysicsView.AppendFlags(DebugViewFlags.PolygonPoints);
            debugPhysicsView.AppendFlags(DebugViewFlags.CenterOfMass);

            //Load our game map, we should probably load the level name(map) from 
            //a text file
            gameMap = Content.Load<Map>("Test Map");

            //we have loaded the map, we need to add Physics Objects
            //to represent this. We have decided that layer called Game
            //will have physics
            TileLayer tileLayer = gameMap.GetLayer("Main Level Layer") as TileLayer;

            int xindex = 0;
            int yindex = 0;
            //Start position of tiles
            float xPos = 0f;
            float yPos = 0f;
            //Nested for loop to go through every tile in the layer
            for (int y = 0; y < tileLayer.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < tileLayer.Width; x++)
                {
                    //if we have a tile at position x, y
                    if (tileLayer.Tiles[x, y] != null)
                    {
                        //Retrieve that tile
                        Tile currentTile = tileLayer.Tiles[x, y];
                        //Grab the propery called tile type from the tile, this was
                        //created in Tiled editor
                        int tileType = (int)currentTile.Properties["TileType"];



                        //Retrieve the size of the tile
                        Vector2 size = new Vector2(currentTile.Source.Width,
                            currentTile.Source.Height);

                        //Get the position
                        Vector2 pos = new Vector2(xPos, yPos);
                        //We need to offset the position to the center of the tile
                        pos += size / 2;
                        //create the body for the tile
                        Body b = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, PhysicsUtils.ConvertToPhysicsUnits(size.X),
                            PhysicsUtils.ConvertToPhysicsUnits(size.Y), 1f, PhysicsUtils.ConvertToPhysicsUnits(pos));


                        //Make the body static, pinned in place
                        b.BodyType = BodyType.Static;
                        //set the user type of the body, this allows us to associate some kind of data with
                        //the body and 
                        b.UserData = tileType;
                        if (tileType == 3)
                        {
                            //Create Game Sprite
                            movingPlatform = new GameSprite();

                            //Load the texture and asign it to the texture property of the the new sprite
                            movingPlatform.Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Test Sprite"); //  40 x 40 - 1m x 1m

                            //Convert screen center from pixels to meters, we could grab this position
                            //from a tile
                            movingPlatform.Position = PhysicsUtils.ConvertToPhysicsUnits(screenCenter) + new Vector2(-1.5f, -1.5f);

                            //Create the RigidBody of the player, we could change this to some other kind
                            //rigid body or a combination of rigid bodies
                            movingPlatform.RigidBody = b;
                            //Under simulation control
                            movingPlatform.RigidBody.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
                            movingPlatform.RigidBody.OnCollision += new OnCollisionEventHandler(platform_OnCollision);
                            movingPlatform.RigidBody.IgnoreGravity = true;
                            movingPlatform.RigidBody.LinearVelocity = new Vector2(-10.0f, 0.0f);
                            movingPlatform.RigidBody.FixedRotation = true;
                            movingPlatform.RigidBody.Mass = 1000f;
                            //sprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity = new Vector2(0,0);

                            //// Give it some bounce and friction
                            //movingPlatform.RigidBody.Restitution = bounce;
                            //movingPlatform.RigidBody.Friction = friction;

                            //Register a collision handler for the moving sprite
                            //movingPlatfrom.RigidBody.OnCollision += new OnCollisionEventHandler(RigidBody_OnCollision);
                            // sprite.RigidBody.FixedRotation = true;

                            //Add it to the display list
                            displayList.Add(movingPlatform);
                            //xindex = x;
                            //yindex = y;
                            tileLayer.Tiles[x, y] = null;
                        }

                    }

                    //Move the new position to the next tile position on the x
                    xPos += PhysicsUtils.MeterInPixels;

                }
                //reset back to the starting x position
                xPos = 0f;
                //Move the new position to the next tile position on the y
                yPos += PhysicsUtils.MeterInPixels;
            }
            tileLayer.Tiles[xindex, yindex] = null;



            //Create Game Sprite
            GameSprite sprite = new GameSprite();

            //Load the texture and asign it to the texture property of the the new sprite
            sprite.Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Test Sprite"); //  40 x 40 - 1m x 1m

            //Convert screen center from pixels to meters, we could grab this position
            //from a tile
            sprite.Position = PhysicsUtils.ConvertToPhysicsUnits(screenCenter) + new Vector2(-1.5f, -1.5f);

            //Create the RigidBody of the player, we could change this to some other kind
            //rigid body or a combination of rigid bodies
            sprite.RigidBody = BodyFactory.CreateCircle(world, PhysicsUtils.MeterInPixels
                / PhysicsUtils.ConvertToGraphicsUnits(2f),
                1f, sprite.Position);
            //Under simulation control
            sprite.RigidBody.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
            //sprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity = new Vector2(0,0);

            //// Give it some bounce and friction
            sprite.RigidBody.Restitution = bounce;
            sprite.RigidBody.Friction = friction;
            //Register a collision handler for the moving sprite
            sprite.RigidBody.OnCollision += new OnCollisionEventHandler(RigidBody_OnCollision);
            // sprite.RigidBody.FixedRotation = true;

            //Add it to the display list
            displayList.Add(sprite);
            ////this is the sprite we are controlling
            playerSprite = sprite;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content. We might change this later on when we
        /// need to load a level at a time
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            //string[] menuItems = { "Start", "Options", "Quit"};

            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            startScreen = new StartScreen(this, spriteBatch, Content.Load<SpriteFont>("menufont"), Content.Load<Texture2D>("image1"));
            Components.Add(startScreen);
            startScreen.Hide();


            actionScreen = new ActionScreen(this, spriteBatch, Content.Load<Texture2D>("image4"));
            Components.Add(actionScreen);
            actionScreen.Hide();

            optionsScreen = new OptionsScreen(this, spriteBatch, Content.Load<SpriteFont>("menufont"), Content.Load<Texture2D>("image2"));
            Components.Add(optionsScreen);
            optionsScreen.Hide();

            quitScreen=new PopUpScreen(this, spriteBatch, Content.Load<SpriteFont>("menufont"), Content.Load<Texture2D>("image3"));
            Components.Add(quitScreen);
            quitScreen.Hide();

            activeScreen = startScreen;
            activeScreen.Show();

            //menuComponent = new MenuComponent(this, spriteBatch, Content.Load<SpriteFont>("menufont"), menuItems);
            //Components.Add(menuComponent);

        }


        public void movePlatform()
        {
            //movingPlatform.RigidBody.ApplyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-1000.0f, 0.0f));
            //movingPlatform.RigidBody.Position = new Vector2(movingPlatform.RigidBody.Position.X - 0.02f, movingPlatform.RigidBody.Position.Y);
            /*count++;
            if (count > 0 && count < 120)
            {
                movingPlatform.RigidBody.Position = new Vector2(movingPlatform.RigidBody.Position.X - 0.02f, movingPlatform.RigidBody.Position.Y);
            }

            count++;
            if (count > 120 && count < 241)
            {
                movingPlatform.RigidBody.Position = new Vector2(movingPlatform.RigidBody.Position.X + 0.02f, movingPlatform.RigidBody.Position.Y);
            }

            if (count > 241)
            {
                count = 0;
            }*/

            //movingPlatform.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
            //movingPlatform.IgnoreGravity = true;
            //movingPlatform.FixedRotation = true;
            //movingPlatform.ApplyForce(new Vector2(-5f,0f));


        }


        /// <summary>
        /// The Collision handler
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fixtureA">The fixture(contains body) which is on the left side of +=</param>
        /// <param name="fixtureB">The fixture(contains body) which has been collided by the above</param>
        /// <param name="contact">Extra contact information</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        bool RigidBody_OnCollision(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB, Dynamics.Contacts.Contact contact)
        {
            //Cast the user data from fixture B's body and check it
            if ((int)fixtureB.Body.UserData == 3)
            {
                //this.Exit();
                playerSprite.Position = new Vector2(movingPlatform.Position.X, movingPlatform.Position.Y);

            }

            if ((int)fixtureB.Body.UserData == 2)
            {
                //need to write code to destroy playersprite here

                displayList.Remove(playerSprite);
                playerSprite.RigidBody.IgnoreCollisionWith(fixtureB.Body);
                playerDead = true;
                gameEnds = true;
                count2 = 10;
            }

            else
            {
                count2 = 0;
            }

            return true;
        }

        bool platform_OnCollision(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB, Dynamics.Contacts.Contact contact)
        {
            if (fixtureB.Body != playerSprite.RigidBody)
            {
                float xvel = movingPlatform.RigidBody.LinearVelocity.X;
                xvel *= -1;
                movingPlatform.RigidBody.LinearVelocity = new Vector2(xvel,0.0f);
                //return true;
            }
            return true;

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

            if (activeScreen == startScreen)
            {
                HandleStartScreen();
            }

            if (activeScreen == optionsScreen)
            {
                HandleOptionsScreen();
            }

            if (activeScreen == quitScreen)
            {
                HandleQuitScreen();
            }
            if (activeScreen == actionScreen)
            {
                HandleActionScreen();
            }
            if (game == true)
            {
                if (CheckKey(Keys.Escape))
                {
                    activeScreen.Enabled = false;
                    activeScreen = quitScreen;
                    activeScreen.Show();
                }
                //Call to deal with game pad controls
                HandleGamePad();
                //Call to deal with keyboard controls
                HandleKeyboard();
                movePlatform();
                //Update physics first, never lest than 30 FPS
                world.Step(Math.Min((float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds, (1f / 30f)));
            }

            if (gameEnds == true)
            {
                game = false;
                activeScreen = actionScreen;
                activeScreen.Show();
            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
            oldKeyboardState = keyboardState;
                        //HandleKeyboard();
        }
        private void HandleActionScreen()
        {
            if (CheckKey(Keys.Enter))
            {
                actionScreen.Hide();
                activeScreen = startScreen;
                startScreen.Show();
                gameEnds = false;
            }
        }

        private void HandleStartScreen()
        {
            if (CheckKey(Keys.Enter))
            {
                if (startScreen.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    activeScreen.Hide();
                    //activeScreen = actionScreen;
                    //activeScreen.Show();
                    LoadGame();
                    game = true;
                }
                if (startScreen.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    activeScreen = optionsScreen;
                    startScreen.Hide();
                    optionsScreen.Show();
                }
                if (startScreen.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    this.Exit();
                }
            }
        }

        private void HandleOptionsScreen()
        {
            if (CheckKey(Keys.Enter))
            {
                if (optionsScreen.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {

                }
                if (optionsScreen.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {

                }
                if (optionsScreen.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    optionsScreen.Hide();
                    startScreen.Show();
                    activeScreen = startScreen;
                    //selected index has to be changed to allow user to change between menus
                    optionsScreen.SelectedIndex = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        private void HandleQuitScreen()
        {
            if (CheckKey(Keys.Enter))
            {
                if (quitScreen.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    activeScreen.Hide();
                    activeScreen = startScreen;
                    activeScreen.Show();
                    game = false;
                }
                if (quitScreen.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    activeScreen.Hide();
                }
            }
        }

        private bool CheckKey(Keys theKey)
        {
            return keyboardState.IsKeyUp(theKey) && oldKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(theKey);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This is used to update the joypad state
        /// </summary>
               private void HandleKeyboard()

        {
            if (playerDead == false)
            {

                //Get the current keyboard state
                KeyboardState state = Keyboard.GetState();

                // Switch between player and camera control
                if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift) || state.IsKeyDown(Keys.RightShift))
                {
                    // Move camera
                    if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                        cameraPosition.X += 1.5f;

                    if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                        cameraPosition.X -= 1.5f;

                    if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
                        cameraPosition.Y += 1.5f;

                    if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                        cameraPosition.Y -= 1.5f;

                    view = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(cameraPosition - screenCenter, 0f)) *
                            Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(screenCenter, 0f));
                }
                else
                {
                    // We make it possible to rotate the circle body
                    if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                        playerSprite.RigidBody.ApplyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-playerSpeed, 0f));

                    if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                        playerSprite.RigidBody.ApplyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(playerSpeed, 0f));

                    if (state.IsKeyUp(Keys.A) && oldKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                    {
                        //playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity = new Vector2(velocity, playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity.Y);

                    }

                    if (state.IsKeyUp(Keys.D) && oldKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                    {
                        //playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity = new Vector2(velocity, playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity.Y);

                    }

                    if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && oldKeyState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
                    {

                        if (count2 < jumpTimes)
                        {
                            playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity = new Vector2(playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity.X, 0f);
                            playerSprite.RigidBody.ApplyForce(new Vector2(0, -jumpHeight * 75));
                            count2++;

                        }
                    }

                    if (!(state.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)) && !(state.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)))
                    {
                        playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity = new Vector2(playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity.X / 2 * friction, playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity.Y);
                    }

                    if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.F1) && oldKeyState.IsKeyUp(Keys.F1))
                        debugPhysicsView.Enabled = !debugPhysicsView.Enabled;

                    if (playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity.X > playerSpeed)
                    {
                        playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity = new Vector2(playerSpeed, playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity.Y);
                    }
                    if (playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity.X < -playerSpeed)
                    {
                        playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity = new Vector2(-playerSpeed, playerSprite.RigidBody.LinearVelocity.Y);
                    }


                }

                // if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                //  Exit();

                oldKeyState = state;
                //oldKeyboardState = keyboardState;
            }


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            //Clear the screen
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            //Begin a sprite batch
            //batch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, view);
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null);
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);


            if (game == true)
            {
                GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

                spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, view);
                //draw map
                gameMap = Content.Load<Map>("Test Map");

                gameMap.Draw(spriteBatch);

                //Cycle through game sprites
                foreach (GameSprite s in displayList)
                {
                    // Convert physics position (meters) to screen coordinates (pixels)
                    Vector2 pos = PhysicsUtils.ConvertToGraphicsUnits(s.RigidBody.Position);
                    Vector2 origin = new Vector2(s.Texture.Width / 2f, s.Texture.Height / 2f);
                    float rotation = 0;

                    //Draw sprite
                    spriteBatch.Draw(s.Texture, pos, null, Color.White, rotation, origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
                }

                spriteBatch.End();

                //Draw debug display
                debugView = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(PhysicsUtils.ConvertToPhysicsUnits(cameraPosition - screenCenter), 0f)) *
                            Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(PhysicsUtils.ConvertToPhysicsUnits(screenCenter), 0f)); ;
                debugProjection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, PhysicsUtils.ConvertToPhysicsUnits(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width),
                    PhysicsUtils.ConvertToPhysicsUnits(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height), 0, 0, 1f);
                debugPhysicsView.RenderDebugData(ref debugProjection, ref debugView);


                //Begin Sprite batch
                spriteBatch.Begin();

                // Display instructions
                spriteBatch.DrawString(gameFont, Text, new Vector2(14f, 14f), Color.Black);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(gameFont, Text, new Vector2(12f, 12f), Color.White);

                spriteBatch.End();

                base.Draw(gameTime);
            }
        }

        public GameSprite sprite { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That huge blob of code isn't going to help anybody. You can't expect that somebody will go through that and provide an answer with code. So the code is basically useless and I hope you remove it (this would actually increase the quality of the question).

Comment: +10 up-votes to bummzack's comment (if I could)

Answer (score 5):

Do what your game does to start up.

The simple, dumb way would be to re-initialize all your objects and variables as they do in the initialization of your game.

You could be clever here, and only reload those elements that are modified during game-play (your models, maps, and textures likely don't change, for instance).

If your character / gameworld has an init method, extract it to a new method, and call that, and when you reload the gameworld, call it again.

Probably this bit of code:

```
    public void LoadGame() { ... }
```